# How to rebase a forked local branch?

Tags: git, github

There is an open source project that I forked.
Then I created a copy of that fork in my local git.

When I want to rebase I do (I don't know if this is a good way but it does work):

```
git checkout main
git fetch project-name
git reset --project-name/main (This make my local like the upstream)
git push --force-with-lease (this makes my forked like the local)
```

Now, say that I did:

```
git checkout mybranch
git commit
git push....
```

I pushed the changes to my forked and opened a PR to the upstream project.
I am requested to rebase my PR with the latest `main`as my branch is over 100 commits behind but I'm not sure how to do that.

My question is how now I can rebase `mybranch` with `upstream/main` or is it preferred to rebase `main` with `upstream/main`  and then rebase `my_branch` with `main`?

Comment: git rebase could be used for this: the official repository had these commits c3,c2,c1, you forked and add c4, c5 but at the same time, in the official repository another contributors added c4,c5,c6,c7 to master. So your fork is outdated. With a successful rebase, your local fork would have the "official" commits c7,c6,c5,c4,c3,c2,c1 and your commits (c3,c2,c1) could be converted to new commits c8,c9,c10. Is this what you need?

Comment: @JRichardsz yes